# Sync outlook between two computers?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook

Is it possible to sync calendar/email/contacts between my work computer and my laptop?

Comment: Do you use Exchange server for Mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Exchange server in the cloud; ie, Google "hosted exchange" and get an account. The going rate is about $5 to $10 per month per email box.

The upside: Outlook syncs everything through the Exchange server and solid email service.

The downside: The monthly cost and selling your soul to the man.

Answer (score 1):

You can install 'evo collaborator for outlook' on both of your outlook installations, then make them to link to the same gmail account.

as a result, all of your outlook installations will have the same copy of contacts, calendars and tasks, and you can make change on any of the outlook, and changes will be synchronized to all devices.

ref link: https://outlookandmacosxserver.blogspot.com/2014/05/sync-gmails-contacts-and-calendar-with.html

Answer (score 0):

check the following links it may help you 
1- http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/sync.asp 
2- http://freelanceswitch.com/working/two-ways-to-sync-outlook-between-computers/ 
3- http://www.ehow.com/way_6138141_can-sync-outlook-desktop-laptop_.html 
4- http://www.synchpst.com/ 
5- http://www.geardownload.com/business/sync2-for-outlook.html

Answer (score 0):

I use my phone. Sync one Outlook to phone, then phone to other Outlook. This is not my clever invention, but a makshift because I could find no other way.