# Merging outlook files on two computers

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sync outlook between two computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/148538/sync-outlook-between-two-computers)

I have two computers laptop and desktop. Both have outlook 2010 and run windows 7 both have identical email accounts all of which are imap. I add contacts to sometimes to one and sometimes to the other and the same for calendar items etc.  I just would like an easy way to periodically update both computers so they are identical--assume email is not an issue -- just contacts etc.  I have read through the microsoft stuff and its mostly email focused but with imap that is not an issue I think.

Answer (score 0):

You're venturing into a hosted solution, or Exchange territory as you are effectively using 2 profiles which are querying the same message store.

Comment: I must be out of my depth here--certainly don't have exchange functions knowingly--just two computers which have same accounts--my only issue is syncing contacts and calendars between the two